# Replicating simulation results

Tags: r, simulation

I am trying to write a simulation based on what [Cuevas et al. (2004)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/223287292_An_ANOVA_test_for_functional_data) did. In the paper they explain the simulation as follows:

$ X_{ij}(t)=m_i(t)+e_{ij}(t); j=1,...,10: $

Here $m_i(t)$ is described as

$m_i(t) = t(1-t), i=1,2,3 $ and where the values $t$ have been chosen equispaced in the interval [0,1].

In a part of the paper, they are saying that $e_{ij}(t)$ is a standard brownian process with dispersion parameter $\sigma$. I took $\sigma_1=0.2$.

```
t <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 25)
x <- rbind(t*(1-t) + cumsum(rnorm(25,0,0.2)),
               t*(1-t) + cumsum(rnorm(25,0,0.2)),
               t*(1-t) + cumsum(rnorm(25,0,0.2)),
               t*(1-t) + cumsum(rnorm(25,0,0.2)),
               t*(1-t) + cumsum(rnorm(25,0,0.2)),
               t*(1-t) + cumsum(rnorm(25,0,0.2)),
               t*(1-t) + cumsum(rnorm(25,0,0.2)),
               t*(1-t) + cumsum(rnorm(25,0,0.2)),
               t*(1-t) + cumsum(rnorm(25,0,0.2)),
               t*(1-t) + cumsum(rnorm(25,0,0.2)))
colnames(x) <- t
```

Here is what I have tried so far. However, I am not getting the correct results using what I have now. I am not sure if I am modeling the error terms correctly and that they follow a standard Brownian motion. I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Why is there a subscript on "$m_i$"?  Its definition does not reference $i,$ suggesting there might be a typographical error.

Comment: $m_i(t)$ does not depend on $i$ for the first case (M1), but it does in subsequent cases (M2-M4). See p. 116.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that $X_{ij}(t)$ should be a 3D array with dimensions ($25$, $k=3$, $10$).

Also, if $\sigma$ is the dispersion parameter, I would think it should be multiplied by the square root of the difference between the discrete $t_r$.

Working with arrays of dimension > 2 is somewhat cumbersome in R since it lacks native broadcasting, but this is my attempt at generating a simulated $X_{ij}(t)$:

```
k <- 3L
n <- 10L
r <- 25L
t <- seq(0, 1, length.out = r)
g <- 1L # subgroup

sigma <- seq(0.2, 5, 0.8)
m <- array(rep(t*(1 - t), k), c(r, k)) # m(t)_i
e <- array(replicate(k*n, cumsum(c(0, rnorm(r - 1L, 0, sigma[g]*sqrt(diff(t)))))), c(r, k, n)) # e(t)_ij
X <- array(c(e) + c(m), c(r, k, n)) # X(t)_ij
dim(X)
#> [1] 25  3 10
# or to get X with dimensions c(3, 10, 25)
X <- aperm(X, c(2:3, 1L)) # X_ij(t)
dim(X)
#> [1]  3 10 25
```

Comment: You need to take the square root of `diff(t)`.  If you were to structure the array appropriately, you wouldn't need `aperm`, either: make the time index the *first* one.

Comment: Yikes, thanks for catching the square root. The dimension ordering depends on further processing. I immediately pictured $i$ and $j$ as the first two dimensions, but, yes, it is easier to make time the first dimension.

Comment: The results don't look right to me.  In particular, I would expect all the $X_{ij}(0)=0,$ but that's not the case.

Comment: Yes, drawing one too many random normals for each time series. Modified to `rnorm(r - 1L, ...`.

Comment: Now it looks right!